# Kendo UI grid - change selected row and expand/collapse group by arrow keys

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

Is it possible to make row navigation in Kendo Grid with arrows, so that when you press the Up and Down buttons, the **selected row** changes, by pressing the Right button a group is expanded, and by pressing the Left button the group collapses?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it yet: The list of supported keys can be found on https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/keyboard-navigation If you really want to have your own keys, you might be able to overwrite it.

Comment: @Carsten Franke, yes, I really want to have my own keys. If you know how to do it, please tell me